# Symmetrically distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of iid random variables, and let $\{Y_n\}$ be another sequence of iid random variables.

Suppose that $P(X_n \leq c) = P(Y_n \geq -c)$ for every real number $c$.

Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $T_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$.

Then, how do I show that 
$$\limsup \dfrac{S_n}{n}  \text { and } \limsup \dfrac{-T_n}{n}$$

are identically distributed?

Intuitively, I am guessing that the fact that the distributions of $X_n$ and $-Y_n$ are the same should give what I want to show, but I cannot figure out how to actually show it.

Comment: Let $Z_n=-Y_n$ for all $n$ and $P(Y_n\geq -c)=P(-Y_n\leq c)=P(Z_n\leq c)$ so $Z_n=X_n$ in distribution.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören But, how does that show limsups have the same distribution?As I wrote, I know that $X_n$ and $Z_n$  have the same distribution

Answer (score 1):

The facts that the sequences $(X_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ and $(Y_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ are independent and that for each $n$, $X_n$ and $-Y_n$ have the same distribution show that the sequence $(X_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ and $(-Y_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ have the same distribution. It follows that 
the sequences $(S_n/n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ and $(-T_n/n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ have the same distribution. Consequently, the sequence $\left(\sup_{n\geqslant N}S_n/n  \right)_{N\geqslant 1}$ and $\left(\sup_{n\geqslant N}-T_n/n  \right)_{N\geqslant 1}$ have the same distribution.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that the two "sequences of random variables " are identically distributed?

Comment: Do you know how the distribution of a sequence of random variables is defined?

Comment: Sorry; please ignore my previous comment. No, I do not know

Comment: I only know the definition of distribution of a single random variable